# How to add 2 google maps with a marker on each Lat/Long point?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image: I'm pretty new to Javascript and I am not able to add a marker to these google maps API's. I was able to add one map with a marker using W3schools tutorial, but when I try to add multiple maps with one marker on each one, this is where I am running into problems. I have searched for an answer on here already, and I was not able to find a working solution. In the picture I have posted, I have not yet added the "var marker" constructor because I am not sure where to put it? Can someone kindly point me in the right direction, and tell me where I am going wrong?]

Javascript in question:

```
function myMap() {
  var mapOptions1 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9814362, -81.2267205),
    zoom:15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
  var mapOptions2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9421287, -81.2284421),
    zoom:15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapOptions1);
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"),mapOptions2);
}
```

What I think I have to add, but not sure where, or even how:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myCenter});

marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your are using file access to your page. Sometimes Google API's restrict that kind of usage. You can get XAMPP to do that. Or even node :)

Comment: I was able to get a marker working on a map using a w3schools tut, but when I tried to add another map, well it just didn't work out. Meaning I can make it work with one map on the screen but not two, so how can I rearrange that javascript to add that var marker function? w3schools has an awesome tut on how to add markers, but they only have 1 map in the examples, and adding another one changes things in the javascript.

Comment: I edited the problem I see on your pic: https://www.pic-upload.de/view-34226230/Inked4vEGn_LI.jpg.html

Comment: Cool story bro, but you're completely ignoring my actual question. If you don't have any actual helpful input, just don't comment. Thanks. Seriously, I can get it WORKING with ONE map, NOT TWO.

Comment: Sorry man, I thought you were refering to the w3schools online sample. Have you tried doing it this way? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=de

Comment: I had tried multiple ways and I wasn't successful until now, but no worries. Thanks anyways and thanks for your help regardless. Sorry for being short before, I thought you were trolling me or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign   a valid center for each marker on each map

```
  function myMap() {
    var mapOptions1 = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9814362, -81.2267205),
      zoom:15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  };
    var mapOptions2 = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9421287, -81.2284421),
      zoom:15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapOptions1);
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"),mapOptions2);

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9814362, -81.2267205)
    });

    marker1.setMap(map1); 

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9421287, -81.2284421)
    });

    marker2.setMap(map2); 

  }
```

Comment: ah okay thanks! my main problem was I didn't know where in the script to add it, but its starting to make sense now. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: Well I had come to the conclusion before I read your answer but since yours is right and definitely would have helped me, I will most definitely hit that green check for you. Thanks again.

Comment: I love this place. It really is an invaluable resource.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I figured it out.

```
  function myMap() {
  var mapOptions1 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9814362, -81.2267205),
    zoom:15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
  var mapOptions2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9421287, -81.2284421),
    zoom:15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapOptions1);
  var latlong = {lat: , lng: }; // Insert your map marker lat/long here
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlong,
    map: map1,
    title: 'Hello World'
  });
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"),mapOptions2);
  var latlong = {lat: , lng: }; // Insert your map marker lat/long here
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlong,
    map: map2,
    title: 'Hello World'
  });
}
```